# ¿mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given? (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

miren tengo un problema el cual ya hay una duda muy similar en este foro pero este esta escrito en json y no me aclaro mucho ya que soy iniciado en programación, no conozco mucho su sintaxis y me confunde a la hora de contrastar información con mi código. Una vez aclarado esto explico mi problema.

He creado un formulario (una iniciación a "crud" lo pongo en comillas porque no llega a CRUD jeje.) para poder insertar los 7 registros que veras a continuación, en la BBDD.

-utilizo XAMPP de servidor local y BRACKETS para picar código.

Antes de que veas el código te pongo justo debajo de esta línea lo errores que me arroja:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\cursoPHPPildoras\resultados_insertar_registros.php on line 43

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\cursoPHPPildoras\resultados_insertar_registros.php on line 45
```

Error al ejecutar la consulta.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="widht=device-width, user-
    scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximun-scale=1, minimun-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

   <?php

    $c_art = $_GET["c_art"];
    $seccion = $_GET["seccion"];
    $n_art = $_GET["n_art"];
    $precio = $_GET["precio"];
    $fecha = $_GET["fecha"];
    $importado = $_GET["importado"];
    $p_orig = $_GET["p_orig"];

    require ("datosconexion.php");

    $conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {

        echo "Fallo al conectar con la Base de Datos.";

        exit();
    }

    mysqli_select_db ($conexion, $db_nombre) or die ("No se encuentra la basede datos.");

    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS (CÓDIGOARTÍCULO, SECCIÓN, NOMBREARTÍCULO, PRECIO, FECHA, IMPORTADO, PAÍSORIGEN) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    $resultado = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sql);

    $ok = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado, "sssssss" , $c_art, $seccion, $n_art, $precio, $fecha, $importado, $p_orig);

    $ok = mysqli_stmt_execute($resultado);

    if($ok == false ) {

        echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta";
    }else{



        echo "Agregado nuevo registro: <br><br>";

        echo $c_art . " " . $seccion . " " . $n_art . " " . $precio . " " . $fecha . " " . $importado . " " . $p_orig . ". <br>";

        mysqli_stmt_close($resultado);

    }


    ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Y a continuación el formulario por no vaya a ser que se escape algo:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Documento sin título</title>
        <style>
            table{
                background-color:#FFC;
                border:1px solid #FF0000;
                margin:auto;
                padding:25px;
            }
        h1{
            width:50%;
            margin:25px auto;
            text-align:center;
            margin-bottom:50px;
        }
        body{
            background-color:#FC9;
        }
        #boton{
            padding-top:25px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1> Alta de artículos nuevos</h1>
        <form action="resultados_insertar_registros.php" method="get">
        <table>
        <tr><td>
            <label>Código Artículo:</label></td><td> <input type="text" name="c_art"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><label>Sección:</label></td><td><input type="text" name="seccion"></td></tr>
          <tr><td>  <label>Nombre Artículo:</label> </td><td><input type="text" name="n_art"></td></tr>
          <tr><td>  <label>Precio: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="precio"></td></tr>
           <tr><td> <label>Fecha: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="fecha"></td></tr>
           <tr><td> <label>Importado:</label> </td><td><input type="text" name="importado"></td></tr>
           <tr><td> <label>País de Origen: </label></td><td><input type="text" name="p_orig"></td></tr>
          <tr><td colspan="2" align="center" id="boton">  <input type="submit" name="enviando" value="¡Dale!"></td></tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Muchas gracias de Antemano, por mas que buscado en google y mirado videos para buscar esta manera, ya que mi profesor nos pego el pantallazo y a el le funciona y he revisado linea a linea infinidad de veces la sintaxis y se me resiste el error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La cosa está en como lo menciona el error en que `mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in`, quiere decir que esperaba un objeto `mysql_stmt` sin embargo se le está pasando un `boolean` por qué?

Bueno, la respuesta está en esta parte del código

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS (CÓDIGOARTÍCULO, SECCIÓN, NOMBREARTÍCULO, PRECIO, FECHA, IMPORTADO, PAÍSORIGEN) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$resultado = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sql);

$ok = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado, "sssssss" , $c_art, $seccion, $n_art, $precio, $fecha, $importado, $p_orig);
```

Tú le estás pasando `$resultado` a `mysql_stm_bind_param` como primer parámetro, sin embargo si leemos la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) de `mysql_prepare` nos dice que regresa un objeto `mysql_stmt` (el que espera `mysql_stmt_bind_param`) si todo salió bien, o `false` si ha ocurrido un error.

Entonces por lo que podemos notar, de ahí es de donde sale el booleano, en el `false` que te regresa en `$sql = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS (CÓDIGOARTÍCULO, SECCIÓN, NOMBREARTÍCULO, PRECIO, FECHA, IMPORTADO, PAÍSORIGEN) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";` por lo que quiere decir que tu consulta o tu conexión tienen algún error

Es difícil saber exactamente cual es el error en la consulta o conexión de este lado dado que no tenemos info de tu base de datos, pero puede que el error sea por los acentos que tienes en tu tabla y que pasas en la consulta, intenta poniéndoles comillas inversas

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS (`CÓDIGOARTÍCULO`, `SECCIÓN`, `NOMBREARTÍCULO`, `PRECIO`, `FECHA`, `IMPORTADO`, `PAÍSORIGEN`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Si te sigue marcando el mismo error, revisa bien tu consulta, tu base de datos y tu conexión.